My Free Tier VM Does not show "Always Free" near the VM name
My Free Tier VM Does not show "Always Free" near the VM name
Shape configuration
Shape: VM.Standard.A1.Flex
OCPU count: 4
Network bandwidth (Gbps): 4
Memory (GB): 24
Local disk: Block storage only
Region: ap-mumbai-1
Above is my configuration and instance details. Please see the following screenshot also

Thanks in advance!
